# Django: add additional data in queryset

Tags: python, django, django-views

I've two models:

**Movie**

*Attributes*: name, plot, rating, release_date, photo

**Director**

*Attributes*: name, bio, photo

**Movie** and **Director** models has a many-to-many relationship.

Now in my `movies/views.py` file:

```
def movies_index(request):
    movies = Movie.objects.all()

    for movie in movies:
       movie.directors = movie.directors.all() # tried but in the template it gives me error when accessing by movie.directors   
       # insert directors in every movie object 

    context_data = {
       'movies': movies
    }

    return render(request, 'movies/index.html', context_data)
```

I want to insert directors data in to every movie object. So that the result may be like:

```
[
  {
    name: "12 Angry Man",
    plot: "bla",
    release_date: "1-2132",
    directors: [
      {
         name: "Quentine",
         bio: "Lodfs"
      },
      {
         name: "Tarantino",
         bio: "Lodsdfs"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Or, is there any different approach do do this?

N.B. I'm using Django 1.9, Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a different approach that does not involve looping and executing N more queries to fetch the related director objects.

[prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

> has a similar purpose to select_related, in that both are designed
>   to stop the deluge of database queries that is caused by accessing
>   related objects, but the strategy is quite different.
>
> select_related works by creating an SQL join and including the fields
>   of the related object in the SELECT statement. For this reason,
>   select_related gets the related objects in the same database query.
>   However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from
>   joining across a ‘many’ relationship, select_related is limited to
>   single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.
>
> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each
>   relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to
>   prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done
>   using select_related,

So

```
 Movie.objects.all().prefetch_related('director')
```

Comment: If I do this `Movie.objects.all().prefetch_related('directors')`, how can I get the movie directors in template file?

Comment: That's a different question. Please post another one with your templates if you have trouble with it.

Comment: figured that out myself. Thanks anyway.